# Terraform plan showing changes that already apply

Tags: gitlab, terraform, minio

I have a pipeline that create users in rabbitmq, minio, keycloak, and others applications using terraform, but in Minio i have a problem that is: I run terraform in first time, the pipeline creates bucket, policy and user (so far, so good), but when i run other times, terraform plan show changes that don't exist, becouse i already run pipeline and don't have any changes, as the image show:

[image]

Below my terraform code for Minio:

```
    # Create a bucket.
resource "minio_bucket" "bucket" {
  name = var.namespace
}

resource "minio_user" "user1" {
  access_key = var.namespace
  secret_key = var.password
  policies = [
    minio_canned_policy.policy1.name
    # Note: using a data source here!
    #data.minio_canned_policy.console_admin.name,
  ]
  /*groups = [
    minio_group.group2.name,
  ]*/
  depends_on = [
    minio_canned_policy.policy1,
  ]
}

# Create a policy.
resource "minio_canned_policy" "policy1" {
  name   = "policy1"
  policy = <<EOT
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}"]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}/*"]
        }
    ]
}
EOT
}
```

In rabbitmq, keycloak, for example, all things works fine.

Someone have any idea to resolve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was create a action to each resource:

```
resource "minio_canned_policy" "policy" {
  name = "policy"
  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      Statement = [
        {
          Action = [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
          ]
          Effect = "Allow"
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}*",
          ]
        },
        {
          Action = [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
          ]
          Effect = "Allow"
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}*",
          ]
        },
        {
          Action = [
            "s3:ListBucket",
          ]
          Effect = "Allow"
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}",
          ]
        },
        {
          Action = [
            "s3:GetObject",
          ]
          Effect = "Allow"
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}/*",
          ]
        },
        {
          Action = [
            "s3:PutObject",
          ]
          Effect = "Allow"
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}/*",
          ]
        },
        {
          Action = [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
          ]
          Effect = "Allow"
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}/*",
          ]
        },
      ]
      Version = "2012-10-17"
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an array as it wants in this place:

```
- "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}*"
+ "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::${minio_bucket.bucket.name}*"]
```

Maybe the other detected change will go away after that. If not, it would look like a bug in the provider.

Comment: Even if this _does_ solve it, it's still technically a bug in the provider since a provider is supposed to differentiate between "real" changes vs. differences that are just normalization done by the remote API, so might be worth reporting it upstream to the provider developers in any case.